# does it possible in flutter to reverse the arena detection

Tags: flutter, dart

for example if user want to swipe left in specific area but the real detect action went to other area  , i have image here
[image]

in other word : user swipe left to `container 2` in real finger , but flutter consider `Container 1` is the one area which the finger swipe through ..

is it possible ?

```
Column(
children[

Container( // real detection 
heigh:200,
child: Text('Container1')
),

  GestureDetector(
   onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
    
      int sensitivity = 8;
       if(details.delta.dx < -sensitivity){
    // Left Swipe
     }
     }
child :Container(//real finger swipe
heigh:200,
child: Text('Container2')
)
]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example of how you can use the data from a GuestureDetector to modify another widget that is not a direct child of the GuestureDetector.

The example below uses the provider package so run `flutter pub add provider` in the terminal or manually add it to your `pubspec.yaml` file.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

// This ViewModel will contain data used in the widget that should 
// be affected by the GuestureDetector.
class ActionViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  double xPosition = 0;

  updateXPosition(double value) {
    xPosition += value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

// This widget uses the GestureDetector to update the xPosition 
// variable in the ViewModel.
class ActionElsewhereWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ActionElsewhereWidget({Key? key, required this.model})
      : super(key: key);

  final ActionViewModel model;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
        model.updateXPosition(details.delta.dx);
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 200,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
    );
  }
}

// This widget listens to updates in the ViewModel. The notifyListener 
// method used in the ViewModel's updateXPosition method triggers an 
// rebuild for the Consumer widget.
class ActionWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ActionWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ActionViewModel>(
      builder: (context, model, child) {
        return Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(model.xPosition, 0),
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            height: 200,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

// A screen utilizing the widgets we just made.
class ActionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ActionScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ActionScreen> createState() => _ActionScreenState();
}

class _ActionScreenState extends State<ActionScreen> {
  ActionViewModel model = ActionViewModel();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ChangeNotifierProvider<ActionViewModel>(
        create: (context) => model,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            const Spacer(),
            const ActionWidget(),
            const Spacer(),
            ActionElsewhereWidget(model: model),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Some code to run the above example.
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => const MaterialApp(home: ActionScreen());
}

void main() => runApp(const App());
```